# How can i make layouts in html css javascript

Tags: javascript, html, layout

`For example
if i have four websites all websites have navbar , footer and customer reviews are same

then how can i use website 1 footer on website 4  and website 2 review on  website 3

i check it is possible with react js , angular .. etc but i want simple html , js

```
 <header>
        <object data="header.html" width="100%" height="50"></object>
    </header>
   
    <h1>Welcome to My Website</h1>
    <p>This is the content of the page.</p>
 
    <footer>
        <object data="footer.html" width="100%" height="50"></object>
    </footer>
```